# HTTP query string length with thin web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

When performing a GET request to my rails application (with [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) web server), I got the following error:

`Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.`

The application is part of a prototype for a master thesis, and the use of GET (not POST) requests is most important. Is there a way to change the query string length?

Comment: You'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: I visited that and many other  questions before. My problem is how to change the max length set in the thin gem.

Answer (score 1):

To change the query string max length of thin you have to change its native C extension parser.

Just change this line in the file `ext/thin_parser/thin.c` and regenerate the gem:

`DEF_MAX_LENGTH(QUERY_STRING, (1024 * 10));`

https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/ext/thin_parser/thin.c#L71