# Thin server QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, thin, puma

How can I increase the maximum allowed value for `QUERY_STRING` using either `thin`, `puma`, or `unicorn` web servers in Rails?  I'm attempting to make a POST request to my Rails API that exceeds the limit, and just need to increase the server's maximum threshold

Specific error on POST: `Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.`

I only came across this question in one other place ([HTTP query string length with thin web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720679/http-query-string-length-with-thin-web-server)) and I couldn't quite make sense of the answer (specifically, where does one find the C file to edit in that answer?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find thin.c in something like ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/ext/thin_parser

you'll want to change

```
DEF_MAX_LENGTH(REQUEST_URI, 1024 * 12); 
...
DEF_MAX_LENGTH(QUERY_STRING, (1024 * 10));
```

in this same folder you just need to use the Makefile to reload the thin_parser.so, and to replace the previous thin_parser.so by the new one in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib (seems like the Makefile is not doing it itself)

```
make clean && make && cp thin_parser.so ../../lib/
```

I just made it work that way, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The file in question is in [/ext/thin_parser/thin.c](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/ext/thin_parser/thin.c) within the gem source code. To make the change you want I believe the easiest path would be to fork this gem on Github, publish your changes in your fork, and then bundle your version using the `git:` option in your Gemfile. Like:

```
gem 'thin', git: '<URL to your fork>', branch: '<branch of fork to use>'
```