# Getting Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am sending large data from ajax hence i am getting below error.

Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.

I am using thin server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thin server QUERY\_STRING is longer than the (1024 \* 10) allowed length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132649/thin-server-query-string-is-longer-than-the-1024-10-allowed-length)

Comment: Already i have these two values                       
DEF_MAX_LENGTH(REQUEST_URI, 1024 * 12); 
...
DEF_MAX_LENGTH(QUERY_STRING, (1024 * 10));

Comment: as mentioned in above link